# Align elements at % with css

Tags: css, sass

I am drawing 2 bars, one at 70% and the other at 100%. what I want is to have a tiny triangle pointing at 70%.

I draw my triangle like this:

```
.arrowUp {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```

The thing is if I give left and right margins as 70% and 30% the I expect it to align with the tip at the end of the bar. But I end up with something like this:

[image]

How can I get the tip of the triangle to point at the end of the black bar?

Comment: set negative margin of half the width of the "triangle"

Comment: Alternately set the position -10px since the width of the boders = 10+10 (20) but that would require it to perhaps be a block element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a negative left margin.

```
.arrowUp {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bar1{
  width: 500px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.bar2{
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
.arrowUp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: -10px;

  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar1">
  <div class="bar2">
    <span class="arrowUp"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```